# Get all data with the recent date

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a tables that contain data, sometime with only date and sometimes with 2 date or 3 dates (I'dont know the date). I want just rows of the recent date.
[table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wI1Tr.png)

I tried to use : 
SELECT INDICE,MAX(file_date) FROM table
but it doesn't work

I want just the records of the date 2017/04/26 in the picture above (example only) 
Thanks for helping.

Comment: Please post code, errors, sample data or textual output here as plain-text, not as images that can be hard to read, can’t be copy-pasted to help test code or use in answers, and are hostile to those who use screen readers. You can edit your question to add the code in the body of your question. Use the `{}` button to format any blocks of code, or indent with four spaces for the same effect.

Comment: Might I suggest http://sqlfiddle.com/

Comment: I don't have a lof of experience in stackoverflow that's why

Answer (score 0):

Use the **where** clause and **in** operator!

```
select * from database_name.column_name where date_column_name in ('2017-04-26');
select * from database_name.column_name where date_column_name in ('2017-04-26','2017-03-26');
```

This matches all rows that has any one of the dates given in list, in date_column_name that you specify

EDIT:

The inner query, get the max date , that is the recent date time entry, and you can get all rows for date as

```
select * from database_name.column_name where date_column_name =(select max(date_column_name) from database_name.column_name);
```

Comment: Thanks of your answer, but i have a lot of tables, idon't know the exact date . I want all data of the only the recent date

Comment: the last date entry is it? is the datatype of the date_column is date time or archer?

Comment: in this example i want all data of 26/04/2017 not the 2017-03-2017,and if there is an other date for example 2017-02-26. I want retrieve only data of 2017-04-26 (the highest) 
the datatype of file_date is DATE in sql server 
thanks for help Keerthana

Comment: I have this data

INDICE file_date
160533 2017-04-26
160479 2017-04-26
160480 2017-04-26
160481 2017-04-26
160482 2017-04-26
160618 2017-04-26
160483 2017-05-13
160534 2017-05-13
160622 2017-05-13
160632 2017-05-13
160642 2017-05-13

and i want only 

160483 2017-05-13
160534 2017-05-13
160622 2017-05-13
160632 2017-05-13
160642 2017-05-13

but in select i'dont know what is the date in the table, because it's change from time to time

Comment: Glad that it helped. If you feel the answer suits your question best, please accept it so that it may help anyone in future facing the same problem.

Comment: How can i do it ?